# javascript Binary operation don't work for options

Tags: javascript, arrays, binary

Here is what i have...
some array item have option that is binary 
like

- $item[0] = 0010
- $item[1] = 1000
- $item[2] = 0110
- $item[3] = 1101

each bit represent some option

what i need is to compare it to the customer request option
let's say it's 0010

so i need the logic to show only $item[0] and $item[2] because second byte is 1. BUT, when there is no customer options check : 0000 i must show them all

only when some options are show there must be filter...

i should have listen more in my math class... i am clueless now, please help !

---

note : 
everything come from here : http://jsfiddle.net/yHxue/
but i dont understand this line : 
`markers[m].setMap(((markers[m].props & props)>>>0===props)? ((props)?map:null): null);`, so i have rewritten it, mine don't work !

Comment: Are the array items strings or numbers?

Comment: `0010` is not binary, it is a decimal number `10`. JavaScript des not support binary literals. Did you mean string `"0010"`?

Comment: a string, because i need to build it from the right to left, but i can convert it to number if needed, it's EZ !

Comment: Why would the item `0` be excluded if customer option is `0010`? Did you mean `0100`?

Comment: it's not, check my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is actual numbers, then just use the bitwise `&` operator on each member.

```
var customerOption = parseInt("0010", 2)

$item.forEach(function(n, i) {
    if (customerOption === 0 || ((n & customerOption) == customerOption))
        alert(i); // show this item
});
```

If they're strings, then you'll need to convert each item to a number first.

Same as above, but...

```
parseInt(n, 2);
```

```js
var $item = [];
$item[0] = "0010"
$item[1] = "1000"
$item[2] = "0110"
$item[3] = "1101"

var customerOption = parseInt("0010", 2)

$item.forEach(function(n, i) {
    if (customerOption === 0 || ((parseInt(n, 2) & customerOption) == customerOption))
        document.querySelector("pre").textContent += "\n0010 matched index: " + i;
});

document.querySelector("pre").textContent += "\n\n"

var customerOption = parseInt("0110", 2)

$item.forEach(function(n, i) {
    if (customerOption === 0 || ((parseInt(n, 2) & customerOption) == customerOption))
        document.querySelector("pre").textContent += "\n0110 matched index: " + i;
});
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: I am not familar with operator... but now the code is... if one bit is On or the other bit is on then... what i need is, one bit on AND, not or... what will be the change in the code

Comment: @menardmam: Not sure what you mean. Are you saying that the `customerOption` will have two bits to test? Can you give an example?

Comment: so if customer ask for 0110 then ONLY [3] will have it....deeper explaination... if a=1010101011 and b=0000000011 and customer ask for 0000000011 then both have the last two bit on, the a+b show ! is it clear ?

Comment: @menardmam: Change `!= 0` to `== customerOption`. The `&` operator is going to return any of the bits that matched, so if you compare it to the original value, it will only be `true` if they all matched. ***DEMO:*** https://jsfiddle.net/gs4so5v6/

Answer (score 1):

Convert all the strings (items as well as the mask) to a number using `parseInt(string, 2)`.

If `mask` is `0`, just take all the items. If not:

Then use the `&` operator to see the common `1` bits:

```
var common = item & mask;
```

Then test `common`:

- If you want any of the mask bits, then `common` should just not be `0`.
- If you want all of the mask bits, then `common` should equal `mask`.

EDIT:

```
markers[m].setMap(
  ((markers[m].props & props) >>> 0 === props) ?
  ((props) ? map : null) :
  null
);
```

`markers[m].props & props` looks for common `1` bits, as I explain above; `>>> 0` makes sure the number is positive. The result is tested against `props`, making sure the common bits are all the bits in `props` (as in my second option above). If all the `props` bits are set, and if `props` is not zero, then `markers[m]` is `setMap`-ped to `map`; otherwise, to `null`.

Comment: the explaination of the line is RELLY helpfull... should choose that as the right answer.... but it's not PERFECT... thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

```
var selections = ['0010', '1000', '0110', '1111'];
var getRequiredSelections = function (customerSelection) {
    var customerSelectionInt = parseInt(customerSelection, 2);
    if (customerSelectionInt) {
        return selections.filter(function (binaryString) {
            return parseInt(binaryString, 2) & customerSelectionInt;
        });
    } else {
        return selections;
    }
};
```

You can use it like so:

```
getRequiredSelections('0010');
```

Answer (score 0):

> BUT, when there is no customer options check : 0000 i must show them all

In 2's compliment, -1 is all `1` in binary

```
if (!props) props = -1;
```

---

Testing for something in binary exactly, use both `&` and `===`

```
needle === (needle & haystack)
```

This means looking for `needle = 1001` in `haystack = 0001` is `false`, even though `1001 & 0001` is the *truthy* `0001`

You may not want to use exact matches in your case

---

You could write some code that takes callbacks to process your array

```
function applyByFlag(flag, callbackTrue, callbackFalse) {
    if (!flag)
        flag = -1;
    function nop() {}
    if (!callbackTrue) callbackTrue = nop;
    if (!callbackFalse) callbackFalse = nop;
    boxes.forEach(function (e, i, a) {
        if (flag & e) // not exact test
            callbackTrue.call(e, e, i, a);
        else
            callbackFalse.call(e, e, i, a);
    });
}
```

Of course, you'd probably want to adjust the test to work against `e.props`

Answer (score 0):

The code you have is almost there; just add an additional check for when `props` is zero:

```
for(var m=0; m < markers.length; m++) {
    var show = (markers[m].props & props)>>>0===props || props == 0;
    markers[m].setMap(show ? map : null);
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yHxue/2/)

The `markers[m].props & props` expression will either be `0` (if not all bits of `props` match) or the value of `props` itself (if all bits of `props` match).

The additional `>>>0` will turn the expression into an unsigned 32-bit integer value, but it's not necessary if you use the following expression:

```
var show = (markers[m].props & props) || props == 0;
```